# What happens when you set to receive charge and you get a critical hit?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, damage, critical-hit

A halberd does triple damage on a critical hit and double damage when set to receive charge.

What happens when you set to receive charge and you get a critical? Is it double or triple damage?

Comment: Did this happen? I mean, in nearly 20 years at this game (including *3.5*), I've only ever once had a PC even be in a position to brace for charge… and the monster charged someone else. To *critically hit* when braced for charge? To me that's like the d20 equivalent of a hole in one.

Comment: It hasn't happen to me.  I know this would be a rare situation but I like using pole arms and was curious if the rules covered it just in case it happened.

Answer (score 19):

## Enjoy *quadruple* damage!

The [Glossary](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/basics-ability-scores/glossary/) on Multiplying says

> When you are asked to apply more than one multiplier to a roll, the multipliers are not multiplied by one another. Instead, you combine them into a single multiplier, with each extra multiple adding 1 less than its value to the first multiple. For example, if you are asked to apply a ×2 multiplier twice, the result would be ×3, not ×4.

A halberd's critical hit multiplier is ×3 and it deals ×2 damage when braced for a charge so a critical hit when its braced for a charge deals ×4 damage.

Comment: You can also see "×2" as "+100%", "×3" as "+200%", etc. and add the "multipliers". So "×3 ×2" becomes "+200%+100%" which is "+300%" or "×4".